# How to position multiple elements on one line, if they are in an absolute element?

Tags: css, position

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="root">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Some text here</a>
        <ul>
            <li>123456</li>
            <li>123456</li>
            <li>123456</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And styles:

```
ul { list-style:none; }

.root {  }
.root > li { position: relative; float:left; margin:0 10px; }
.root > li ul { position: absolute; }
.root > li ul li { float:left; margin:0 10px; }
```

I have also created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U5h9p/

I am trying to position the inner LI's to be on the same line always, no matter how long it will be. The problem is that their parent UL doesn't have fixed width. Is this fixable with CSS only and how? I don't want to use JS unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try .root > li ul li {position:relative; display:inline-block; margin: 0 10 px;} and see if that results in what you are after or not? Oh and remove float:left;  from .root> li

edit:

Try this

```
ul { list-style:none; } 
.root { } 
.root > li { position: relative; display:inline-block; margin:0 10px; } 
.root > li ul { position:absolute; width:350%; padding:0px;} .root > li ul li { position:relative; display:none; } 
.root > li:hover ul li {display:inline-block; margin-right: 10px;}
```

Setting the width on the li ul at over 100% allows the inner list items to line up with display inline-block. I know you don't want a fixed with but assigning a % width will allow it to vary and if your parent ul width is defined in % as well it will all be dynamic and vary with screen size
Just play around with which width works best for your needs

Comment: If I remove the `float:left` from `.root > li`, it works but onnly because the outer `li` takes the whole parent width. In the real situation I have many outer `li`'s on the same line (like a regular first-level menu), so they have to be either floated or `display:inline-block`.